# Which is a better filter for the following noises?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I would like to know the better filter for Gaussian noise and speckle noise on matlab
I tried to use wiener filter for Gaussian but it does not seem to work. Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: What is the nature of the images you are denoising?

Answer (score 5):

Additive Gaussian noise can be removed by any denoising algorithm, it's the standard test case. Speckle is better removed using nonlinear filtering such as a median.

Since there are zillions of image denoising algorithms around there, I recommend you to visit this [tutorial site](http://www.numerical-tours.com) that comes with a lot of exercises using matlab. In your case [this](http://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~peyre/numerical-tour/tours/denoisingsimp_1_noise_models/) and [this other](http://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~peyre/numerical-tour/tours/denoisingsimp_2_linear/) tutorial seem to be a good starting point.

**--EDIT--**

The effect on your noise/image will depend a lot, both on your images and on your noise.

If the noise looks like impulsions (salt-and-pepper noise), then you will usually find that median filtering is a good starting point. If your noise is additive Gaussian (or multiplicative, in which case you can take the log) then a lot of algorithms are good, including Wiener and Kalman filtering.

On the other hand, Wiener filtering will  blur your image. Hence, if you have a lot of texture or sharp details (i.e. high frequency that will be mistaken for noise by your filter), you will often prefer techniques such as median or anisotropic filtering.

Comment: Thank you. I tried using median filter for speckle, but not much of the noise went. I used wiener for speckle and it worked better. IS that even possible? My images were gray scale images.